Why do I need to return fetch in a NextJS API Route?
I am learning about API Routing in NextJS. Making the route for a login function, I discovered that if I don't return the fetch in my route, the whole process breaks.
Here's my code:
// '/src/app/api/login/route.ts`

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { username, password } = await request.json();

  const IP = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CASA_IP;
  return fetch(`http://${IP}:4000/api/routers/users/login`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      password: password
    })
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      return NextResponse.json(data);
    })
}

But when make the fetch petition to the API Route from the frontend, I do not need that return:
// '/src/app/components/LoginComp.tsx`

const login = ({ username, password, event }:{ username:string, password:string, event:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> }) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!username || !password) {
    alert("provide all fields");
    return;
  }

  fetch('/api/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      password: password
    }),
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.user.token)
      localStorage.setItem('username', data.user.username)
      window.location.href = "/dashboard";
    })
}

Could someone explain to me what is the purpose of that return?
I tried changing the Route's logic to an async/await function, but still wasn't able to understand why you need to return the fetch, or even await it:
// '/src/app/api/login/route.ts`

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { username, password } = await request.json();

  const IP = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CASA_IP;
  const res = await fetch(`http://${IP}:4000/api/routers/users/login`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username as string,
      password: password as string,
    })
  })

  const data = await res.json();
  return NextResponse.json(data);
}


The short answer is the return inside your .then() does nothing to the parent function. You’re returning a Promise, which you should read about, and how async functions work. Without returning the promise, you’re saying “kick off a fetch, don’t return anything, and I’m done with the route entirely”, and then much later, the fetch finishes, and calls your .then(), which is floating out in space.
